# jquery select2 - Select all options with inputted text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

What i'm trying to achieve here is I have a text input, and when I type in a string for example "HELP" -  I want all the option texts that are "HELP" to be auto-selected in the list.

Sorry I should mention im using the select2 plugin for jquery

example-->

html:

```
<select id="select2" name="select2" multiple class="select2" style="width: 300px;">
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">BPS</option>
<option value="3">BPS</option>
<option value="4">HELP</option>
<option value="5">HELP</option>
<option value="6">EX</option>
<option value="7">HELP</option>    
</select>

<br /><br />

<input type="button" name="Button" id="selectspecify" value="Select String" />&nbsp;
<input size="50" name="selectstring" id="selectstring" value="" placeholder="Type in an option name">
```

jquery:

```
$('#selectspecify').click(function() {
    var selectstring = $('#selectstring').val();

    $('#select2\\[\\] option:contains(' + selectstring + '))').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end().select2() 

});

$(".select2").select2();
```

Can someone help me with this please?

I've made a jsfiddle to show what i'm trying todo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZhWu/2/
But it obviously doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#selectspecify').click(function() {
    var selectstring = $('#selectstring').val();
    var stringVal = [];
    $('#select2').find('option').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':contains(' + selectstring + ')')){
                  stringVal.push($(this).val());
        }
        $('#select2').val(stringVal).trigger("change");
    });
});

$(".select2").select2();
```

Ref: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZhWu/3/)

Comment: Just a question... if I just wanted to *ADD* these options that were found from the input string how would i do that?  Because everytime I type "HELP" then hit the button its good..but then if I want to add additional "BPS" to the multi list all the previous HELPS disappear... i know this wasnt part of my orig question..just if u know.. greatly appreciated

Comment: @rubberchicken: Use this http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/3ZhWu/4/. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectspecify').click(function() {
    $('#select2').select2("val", $('#select2 option:contains(' + selectstring + ')')
    .map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get());
});
```

Try:
http://jsfiddle.net/L4ob780b/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "option:contains('Help')" );
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: doesnt work for me... you wanna try to get it to work with my jsfiddle?

Comment: Maby this could help you ;) (not an answer just for reference) http://mobifreaks.com/html5-data-attributes-search-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#selectspecify').click(function() {
    var selectstring = $('#selectstring').val().toLowerCase();

$('#select2 option').each(function() {

    var inval = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    console.log(inval);
    if(inval.indexOf(selectstring) != -1) {

        $(this).prop('selected',true);
    }
});
});
```

This one actually checks for substring. so even if you give 'h'. It will select the options.
If you want exactly same string use an equality check.